# What's $[L:K(\alpha)]$ here?

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

Let $L=\mathbb{Q}(T_1,T_2,T_3,T_4)$ be a purely transcendental extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, and percieve $S_4$ on $\{T_1,T_2,T_3,T_4\}$ as subgroup of Aut$(L)$. Write $K=L^{S_4}$. Calculate $[L:K(\alpha)]$ for:

$\alpha=T_1+T_2+T_3+T_4$

$\alpha=T_1+T_2+T_3$

$\alpha=T_1+T_2$

$\alpha=T_1$

It seems to me that $\alpha=T_1+T_2+T_3+T_4$ is already in $K$ because it is invariant under all elements of $S_4$. But to me for all $\alpha$ the degree seems infinite, which must be wrong?

Comment: Can you specify exactly what you mean by $L^{S_4}$?

Comment: The elements of $L$ that are invariant under all elements of $S_4$

Comment: @DanZimm: I'm betting its the fixed subfield of $L$ under the action of $S_4$; let's hope our OP chimes in soon!

Comment: What did I tell y'all?

Comment: Are you familiar with the theorem of Artin that says that for a field $E$ and a finite group of automorphisms $G$ that $E/E^G$ is a Galois extension?

Comment: Ah, however I have no idea how that Galois group would be, it seems huge?

Comment: Let's say you put all $T_1,T_2,T_3,T_4$ in the basis of $L$ over $L^{S_4}$ How would you get $T_1^2$ by linear combinations without adding it itself?

Comment: Ah: $T_1(T_1+T_2-T_1T_2)=T_1^2$

Comment: Never mind the last comment